# How to change button height and not affect other buttons?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Am trying to make a calculator similar to the attached image below:

[image]

But I couldn't align the equal to button properly. How can I make it similar to that equal to button in the image?

Here's a snippet:

```css
#container
{
 text-align: center;
 margin: 200px auto;
}

button
{
 width: 30px;
 margin: 0 auto;
}

#clear, #zero
{
 width: 65px;
}

#equal
{
 height: 65px;
}
```

```html
 <div id="container">
  <div id="display">
  </div>
  <button id="clear">CLEAR</button>
  <button value="/">÷</button>
  <button value="*">x</button><br><br>
  <button value="7">7</button>
  <button value="">8</button>
  <button value="9">9</button>
  <button value="-">-</button><br><br>
  <button value="4">4</button>
  <button value="5">5</button>
  <button value="6">6</button>
  <button value="+">+</button><br><br>
  <button value="1">1</button>
  <button value="2">2</button>
  <button value="3">3</button><br><br>
  <button id="zero" value="0">0</button>
  <button value=".">.</button>
  <button id="equal" value="=">=</button>
 </div>

 <script type="text/javascript" src="Calculator.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Why did you tag bootstrap? I don't see you use it. If you are, i'd suggest using rows and cols. That should do it I think

Comment: Well, if browser support isn't a concern, you could use CSS Grid. [Some examples at Grid by Example](https://gridbyexample.com/)

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
#container
{
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 200px;
}

button
{
    width: 30px;
}

#clear, #zero
{
    width: 65px;
}

#equal
{
  position: absolute;
  margin-left: 52px;
  margin-top: -72px;
  height: 72px;
}

#buttons
{
    display: inline-block;
}

#float
{
    float: left;
}
```